# In MAYA 2009, is it possible to capture the cube rotate event?

Tags: python, events, 3d, maya

I need to call a function ( Maya-Python ) based on cube rotationX. For that I have to capture the event, programmatically.

I tried using while loop but It stucks in the loop, Nothing can be done in that time.
I tried theading (python), still same.

Can it be done this or other way? If yes, How?

*Maya 2009 in Windows XP*

Some failed code references:

```
import maya.cmds as cmds    
while (count < 90):
     lock = cmds.getAttr('pCube1.rotateX',lock=False)
     print lock
     count = count + 1
```

Here Python wise:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

    import thread
    import time

# Define a function for the thread
def cubeRotateX( threadName, delay):
   count = 0
   while count < 5:
      time.sleep(delay)
      count += 1
try:
   thread.start_new_thread( cubeRotateX, ("Thread-1", 2, ) )
except:
   print "Error: unable to start thread"

while 1:
   pass
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like a scriptJob may be what you're after.  Here's a simple example below.  However, in this example the callback will only be called when you release the mouse from rotating.

```
import maya.cmds

def myRotateCallback():
    print 'do something'

maya.cmds.scriptJob( attributeChange=['pCube1.rotateX', myRotateCallback] )
```

If you want to receive continuous callbacks while rotating the cube, you can do that at the maya API level with MNodeMessage::addNodeDirtyPlugCallback.

Comment: Worked Nicely .. is there some tutorial for these kind of activities. (If it is there in Maya Docs then its ok.)